# Searching for Swedish Mac game from the early 1990's where you try to sneak out of the house

Tags: identify-this-game, mac-os-classic

I was given a funny, obscure game for Mac sometime in the 1994 to 1996 timeframe.  Unfortunately I have no idea what the game was called, but I'd like to track it down.

The game, which was in color, had a single play screen which showed two areas: a home (kitchen and bedroom) where you and your mother live, and a bar which was shown above the home.  The object of the game was to sneak out of your bedroom and go to the bar and get a beer.  From time to time, the mother would walk from the kitchen to your bedroom to check on you, and punish you if you were found not to be in your bed.  You scored points for getting a beer, and lost a life when you got caught out of your bedroom by your mother.  The more beers you had, the more often you would trip, which would make it more difficult to get back into the bedroom in time.

The game was entirely in Swedish.  One phrase from the instructions that I remember distinctly was "Springa vanster", which I believe means "run left".  One of the notable features of the game was that when you snuck out of your bedroom, your character left the game window entirely and ran/climbed across your Mac desktop until he reached the bar area, where he climbed back in the game window.  For that era, it was pretty slick graphics coding to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be "[Dubbelmoral](https://www.macintoshrepository.org/5297-dubbelmoral-)" ([Swedish wikipedia](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubbelmoral_(datorspel))).

Comment: To anybody who comes here and reads this: You absolutely have to click on the "Dubbelmoral" link above and go watch the youtube video of the game.  Glugging beer, barfing, pissing against the side of the building, smooching random girls, ... all with primitive sound bites ... the game is hilarious!